# Filtering a loaded kml file in OpenLayers

Tags: filter, openlayers, kml

I'm trying to create an interactive search engine (for finding event tickets) of which one of its features is a visual map that shows related venues using OpenLayers.  I have a plethora of venues (3000+) in a kml file that I would like to selectively show a filtered subsection of.  Below is the code I have but when I try to run it has a JavaScript error.  Running firebug and chrome developer tools makes me think that it is not getting passed the parameters I give because it says that the variables are null.  However, I cannot figure out why they are not getting passed.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

```js
var map, drawControls, selectControl, selectedFeature, select;
$('#kml').load('venuesComplete.kml');
kml=$('#kml').html();
function showVenues(state, city, venue){
    filterStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Filter({});
    var kmllayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
    strategies: [filterStrategy,
        new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "venuesComplete.kml",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
        extractStyles: true,
        extractAttributes: true
        })
    })
    });
    select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(kmllayer);
    kmllayer.events.on({
        "featureselected": onFeatureSelect,
        "featureunselected": onFeatureUnselect
    });
    map.addControl(select);
    select.activate();
    filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE,
        property: "",
        value: ""
    });
    function clearFilter(){
        filterStrategy.setFilter(null);
    }
    function setFilter(property, value){
        filter.value = value;
        filter.property = property;
        filterStrategy.setFilter(filter);
    }
    var vector_style = new OpenLayers.Style();
    if(venue!=""){
        setFilter('name', venue);
    }else if(city!=""){
        setFilter('description', city);
    }else if(state!=""){
        setFilter('description', state);
    }
    map.addLayer(kmllayer);
    function onPopupClose(evt) {
        select.unselectAll();
    }
    function onFeatureSelect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        var selectedFeature = feature;
        var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
            new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
            "<h2>"+feature.attributes.name + "</h2>" + feature.attributes.description +'<br>'+feature.attributes, 
            null, 
            true, 
            onPopupClose
        );
        document.getElementById('venueName').value=feature.attributes.name;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=event.feature.id;
        feature.popup = popup;
        map.addPopup(popup);
    }
    function onFeatureUnselect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        if(feature.popup) {
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            delete feature.popup;
        }
    }
}
function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    var google_map_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        'Google Map Layer',
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID}
    );
    map.addLayer(google_map_layer);
    state="";
    state+=document.getElementById('stateProvDesc').value;
    city="";
    city+=document.getElementById('cityZip').value;
    venue="";
    venue+=document.getElementById('venueName').value;
    showVenues(state,city,'Michie Stadium');
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}));
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF I UNDERSTAND CORRECTLY, your kml does not load properly.  if this is not the case, please disconsider my answer.

it is very important to check if your kml layer was properly loaded.  i have a map that loads multiple dynamic (from php) kml layers and it is not uncommon to have a large layer simply not load.  when that happens, the operation is aborted, but, as far as openlayers is concerned, the layer was properly loaded.

so i do 2 things: i check if the amount of loaded data meets the expected number of features in my orginal php kml parser (i use a jquery or ajax call for that) and then, in case there is a discrepancy, i try reloading (since this is a loop, i limit it to 5 attempts, so as not to loop infinitely).

check out some of my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995238/how-to-refresh-reload-a-kml-layer-in-openlayers-dynamic-kml-layer/11333611#11333611)