# Route a location from start , while driving and end point

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am creating a Map routing App for my colleagues to track their locations as trips. 
How can I do the following:

I **get their current location** when app starts and **create a marker**, when they start driving, I want to **draw a line** from Start marker and **follow their trip** into work and then end the trip with another marker.

I am using **Google API** v1. My company has a users license. . I have seen many posts using a RouteOverlay, but that never works for me.  I just want a route to follow a driver while driving.

I work for a company that is an m2m platform which has location, etc built in. There is already an IOS app that Apple users here use. **They open the app, it gets a location and while they drive, it does an httppost to our platform**. www.axeda.com

I am trying to **mimic this on Android**, where I start the app, it gets the currentlocation and posts it to our server and then while I drive, every 200ft it will post the location until I stop the trip. I am trying to have a path/route drawn from start point, in trip until trip ends. I hope that clarifies it. (DB, Tomcat, WebApp, etc is our business)

If you could start me off with some code that shows location A to B has a route and then I emulate a changed location to C and it routes there, I will be well on my way

Comment: friends who have 3K rep at least, please consider reopening this question, now that it has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MARCH 13th:
skip all this text and the two pretty pictures and read from the part that has a "MARCH 13th 2013 EDIT:" tag onwards.

please clarify:

1. what mapping api are you planning on using?  googleMaps will charge you 25 dollars per person tracked in increments of, at least, 100 users (last quote that i received), unless it is a 100% free, userless app with under a certain number of pageviews.
2. where do you plan on viewing the map (smartphone/tablet or web)?

i recommend that you use OpenLayers.  there are [many examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) that will help you to understand the way it works.

in case what you want to do is something like this:

[image: animated OPENLAYERS MAP]

you will need to use a LAMP server (linux, apache, mysql, php), with either open ports or using a very insecure "post to http" strategy, as well as openlayers using the "refresh strategy".

in case you want a static map, like this (sorry, there IS a flag at the beginning, but i didnt have any image with it - believe me, it is there, just outside the frame):

[image: map with track]

then you will NOT use the refresh strategy, but still, this is no walk in the park (the tech is easy, the debugging is a female dog).

dont want to rain on your parade, but, this is, probably, not a weekend project, unless you want it to work, but only sorta...

NOTE: in both cases, i am using a KML source for geodata (parsed from MySQL stored data collected from gps OR wifi on the smartphone - actually my app integrates RFID and vehicle trackers, too).  please check [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995238/refresh-redraw-a-layer-in-openlayers-kml-network-link-auto-refresh/11333611#11333611) on the subject (with proper code on how to do it).

**MARCH 13th 2013 EDIT**
after your explanation, this is how to do it using googleMaps API (as per your comments below):

create a couple of overlays on your map

```
        mapOverlays.add(new MapOverlayTrip(pathTrip));
    mapOverlays.add(new MapOverlayPointer(location));

    //redraw map
    mapView.invalidate();
    flagMapRedraw = false;
```

...

```
public class MapOverlayTrip extends Overlay implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, OnTouchListener {`
```

for example (you may remove the TTS, if your app dont talk).
...

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
    super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);
```

...

```
    PathPoint pathPointTemp;
    Path pathScreenNewArea = new Path();
    Path pathScreen = new Path();
    Point p1 = new Point(0,0);
    Point p2 = new Point(0,0);
    projection = (Projection) mapv.getProjection();
    for (int j = 0; j < pathTrip.size();j++) {
        p1 = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(pathTrip.get(j),p1);
        if (j == 0) {
            pathScreen.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
            p2 = (Point) p1;
        } else {
            pathScreen.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        }
```

using a PathPoint class like

```
public class PathPoint {

public float x;
public float y;
```

which is updated in my main activity

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location locationIn) {
    location = locationIn;
            //redraw map
    geoPoint = locationConvert(location);
    geoPointLast = pathTrip.get(pathTrip.size()-1);
            if (your conditions compare current displacement) {
                 pathTrip.add(geoPoint);
```

these are excerpts from fully functional code that does the plotting on the android screen.

for updating, i do not like http post, i trust sockets better, nevertheless, i have both solutions working in parallel for 6 months and their performance is quite similar (hit / miss ratio). this is the general solution i used to call BOTH socket and http at the same time

```
public boolean geoPointInsert (GeoLocPoint geoPointIn) {
    boolean flagOK = false;
    if (geoPointIn != null) {
        try {
            String webPostAnswer = deviceIdCheck(deviceUuid, geoPointIn);
```

this is the code that takes care of the http post

```
try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        //Log.v(TAG, "okok deviceId = "+deviceUuidIn +" latitude "+geoPointIn.latitude);
        String uri = "http://www.yourdomain.net/tracker/" +
                "trackPointListener.php";
        uri = addLocationToUrl(uri, geoPointIn);
        request.setURI(new URI(uri));
        //Log.i(TAG,uri);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        //Log.d(TAG, "php answered> "+response);
```

IMHO, http has greater liability than socket connections do, though both are potentially subject to denial of service attacks.

as i said, NOT a weekend project.

Comment: Sorry Tony, I have been ill for the last few days and did not get a chance to review your answer. i Appreciate your advice though.

What I am trying to do is on an Android device.

I have all the backend servers, DB , etc. set up.

Comment: All I am doing is getting an App where a emp[loyee will start the App, 
1. it gets current location and sensd that to our platform, then while he/she drives around, it will plot them and send the location to our platform

I need my routeOverlay to work. I have them in my code, but I never see the route showing.

it plots the begin location with a marker, then the dot moves around but has no route/lines.

Comment: @motti10 firstly, what mapping API are you using?  you can get it easily done on android realtime using googlemaps api. BUT, even though you manage to run the app with few users, it is an infringement of their rules of use and your liability can be enormous.  please inform your problem in more detail and we might be able to solve it.

Comment: Tony,
I am using Google API v1. My company has a users license.
I am trying to do what you showed in your movie above.
I have seen many posts using a RouteOverlay, but that never works for me??


I just want a route to follow a driver while driving..

Comment: @motti10 please confirm: u want to update the map on the android while posting user's geolocation in realtime to a mysql database on a web server?  is there ALSO a web mapping service for OTHER users to follow the target's displacement?

Comment: I work for a company that is an m2m platform which has location, etc built in. There is already an IOS app that Apple users here use. They open the app, it gets a location and while they drive, it does an httppost to our platform.  www.axeda.com
I am trying to mimic this on Android, where I start the app, it gets the currentlocation and posts it to our server and then while I drive, every 200ft it will post the location until I stop the trip.
I am trying to have a path/route drawn from start point, in trip until trip ends.
I hope that clarifies it. (DB, Tomcat, WebApp, etc is our business)

Comment: If I drive from location A to B, I want to see a route, then I continue to C, the route follows me to location C, et. etc.

Comment: @motti10 you have made yourself very clear.  YES, you can do this on android.  if you want a general recipe, i can give you the info you need.  i will start by proposing an edit and reopening for your question, now that it is not "not a real question" anymore.

Comment: Tony I really appreciate it.
Any help I can get, I will be thankful

Comment: Tony If you could start me off with some code that shows location A to B has a route and then I emulate a changed location to C and it routes there, I will be well on my way

Comment: @motti10 excerpts from my original code posted (there's 10K+ lines all in all - it's a geobased agriculture inspection app).  as i said, this is NOT a weekend project.  i recommend you buy a customized 3rd party solution to do it.  you could have it up and running by the end of the week and save a bundle on manpower (this is as far as i can go without crossing the fine line of "excessively overt self-promotion").